# Does pdb offer watchpoints?

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, gdb

In gdb, https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html,

> use a watchpoint to stop execution whenever the value of an expression changes, without having to predict a particular place where this may happen.

I searched that for pdb, but it seems there is no watchpoint in pdb. Or am I missing it?

Comment: Wrap `set_trace` in a conditional?

Comment: ...`if value == value_im_waiting_for: pdb.set_trace()`.